# How do you get rid of fog in the nether on Minecraft bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to make a nether arena but from the back seats you can't see the stage what is the command, if there is one, to remove fog from the nether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible via the [`fog` command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/fog) due to how the `remove` operation works:

```
fog <victim: target> <mode: delete> <userProvidedId: string>
```

Take specific notice of the `userProvidedId` argument. This is created when you `push` fog onto an entity, for example:

```
fog @s push "minecraft:fog_hell" "someFog"
```

You would then remove the fog with the command:

```
fog @s remove "someFog"
```

Furthermore, there is no explicitly mentioned ID representing the fog of the nether.